# resque rake task giving error

Tags: resque, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

I have been using resque for background processing, No my problem with code is :
- when I start rake task as "rake resque:work QUEUE='*'" as per ryan bates episode no. 271. in remote server the code inside worker class for file maipulation works properly without any filepath issues and I/O errors.

- when i start rake task as "rake resque:work QUEUE='*' BACKGROUND=yes" now, the code inside worker class gives "failed:Errno::EIO: Input/output error @ io_write - >" error.
Now my question is I want to start the resque queue above rake command only one time and why second point giving error is this issue with filepaths if so then why it runs smoothly as mention in point first.

Comment: try to demonize your resque job something like `RAILS_ENV=staging QUEUE='*' PIDFILE='/shared/pid/resque.pid' BACKGROUND=yes VERBOSE=1 bundle exec rake resque:work` or add `--trace` to trace the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `god` to manage your background process. Or `nohup` can be your solution too as below:

```
$ nohup bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=queue_name PIDFILE=tmp/pids/resque_worker_QUEUE.pid & >> log/resque_worker_QUEUE.log 2>&1
```

and even this command worked for me:

```
PIDFILE=./resque.pid BACKGROUND=yes QUEUE="*" rake resque:work >>  worker1.log &
```

Hope that will help you too.